# Matlab cannot find circles in this picture

Tags: matlab

MATLAB code, returns nothing：

```
A = imread('2.jpg');
imshow(A)
Rmin = 20;
Rmax = 70;
[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(A,[Rmin Rmax],'Sensitivity',0.8);
viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'LineStyle','--');
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [*this self Q/A post*](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/334096-why-does-imfindcircles-not-find-circles-in-my-image) on this topic by Mathworks.

Comment: Thanks a million.